# Google Maps API V3 : weird UI display glitches (with screenshot)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone with any ideas on what's causing this weird glitch with the google maps UI components, be really grateful to hear from you!

[image]

the map is created with:

```
        var options = {
        zoom: <?php echo $this->zoom ?>,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $this->centre_lat ?>, <?php echo $this->centre_lon ?>),
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP                
        }; 

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);
```

and the glitch is the same even with no markers.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

We ran into the same problem.  The css designer was using this style:

**style.css**

```
img {max-width: 100%; }
```

Instead of disabling the zoom control, we fixed the problem by overriding the img style for map_canvas elements like so:

**style.css:**

```
#map_canvas img { max-width: none; }
```

The zoom control now displays correctly.

Setting "img max-width:100%" is a technique employed in responsive/fluid web site design so that images re-size proportionally when the browser is re-sized. Apparently some css grid systems have started setting this style by default.  More info about fluid images here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/  Not sure why this conflicts with the google map...

Comment: This affected me as well. Google Maps API v3 uses a large-dimensioned transparent png sprite image (`http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png`) which is placed inside a parent container with `overflow: hidden`. Thus, limiting the width of the image causes the image to be compressed.

Answer (score 33):

With latest version of google maps api you need this:

```
<style>
  .gm-style img { max-width: none; }
  .gm-style label { width: auto; display: inline; }
</style>
```

Comment: This is the same as the accepted solution, but with a different selector and extra reset of your own label styling.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a problem with the zoom control.  Try adding `zoomControl:false` to your options.

In fact it seems the normal zoom slider is positioned off to the left of the page (use Firebug > Inspect Element).  Could be a CSS conflict?

Comment: Ok found it. it's caused by my `img {max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: I face the same problem and have fix after removing the css img{max-width:100%;} thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well I got the fix for this:

On your CSS you added something like:

```
img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

try not to make it global and it should fix you :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
#map img { max-width: none !important; } (from Patrick's answer)
```

the attribute "!important" makes sure to override any other style, #map is the id assigned when you declare the new object Gmaps:

```
<script>
    map = new GMaps({
          div: '#map',           <-  your id
          lat:  *******,
          lng:  *******,
          scrollwheel: false,
          panControl: true,
          ....
          ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using the Dreamweaver fluid grid feature your default set up should look like this:**

```
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}
```

**Try this:**

```
object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
#map_canvas img { max-width: none; }
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}
```

just replace the code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap (as of version 2.3.2) messes with images in the same way as in the accepted answer.

In fact, I suspect that the design used in Haroldo's website uses Bootstrap.

I'm just posting this because no one else mentioned Bootstrap, and someone might be looking for a Bootstrap-specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on my Square Space website. I did not have access to the CSS style sheet. Since you are embedding an html doc, you can just use inline CSS to fix the problem. I modified the style of the container instead of making a site wide change (which I couldn't do). Here is what I did:

```
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  #map-canvas img {max-width: none;}
</style>
```