# Google Map's Zoom look weird

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map issue, everything seems to working except the Zoom buttons seem messed up

Here is an image of the map.
[image]

I'm guessing that something is overlapping but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 12):

Seems I'm very late, still thought to share my thoughts.

It's not a good idea to edit a library's core css. Rather we can override it

This is what i used.try this

```
#mapDiv img{ max-width: none; }
```

Comment: I found that I also needed to add `position: absolute;` to `.gmnoprint img` in order to override something in Bootstrap framework that had messed up the styling of the controls.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the link you have  provided is not working.

This problem is generally due to the css (I think its bootstrap.css),which makes the google map controls messed up.
Check for the line having code:`max-width:100%`

You will have to remove it.

Check it if it works.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what the problem was. I had to remove max-width: 100%; from the img part of the bootstrap.css

Answer (score 3):

With latest version of google maps api you need this:

```
<style>
  .gm-style img { max-width: none; }
  .gm-style label { width: auto; display: inline; }
</style>
```

answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339767/3041072

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap.css** actually has a class called **google-maps** that will set the max-width of the img to none.
The code in **bootstrap.css** is

> **`#map_canvas img, .google-maps img{max-width:none}`**

Here is a link to the question on StackOverflow: [Twitter Bootstrap CSS affecting Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141249/twitter-bootstrap-css-affecting-google-maps)