# jquery conflict with my google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I used JQuery to create my Google map. However, there are some conflict with other jquery functions that made my map looking like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/l9e.png/ (the zoom control bar on the left is not displaying and working properly). Because I have no idea what could cause the problem, I did not paste my code here. Has anybody met this situation before? Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map's Zoom look weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898973/google-maps-zoom-look-weird)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 : weird UI display glitches (with screenshot)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471830/google-maps-api-v3-weird-ui-display-glitches-with-screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Test the page on Firefox with Firebug installed or On Chrome and use the inspect tools to see if there are Javascript errors.. And check if  the styles/CSS of the Zoom control is being overwritten by other CSS you may have.

Comment: Thx for your replay. I tried commented out js one by one. I finally found that it was a css issue. Got it solved. :D