# google map size slider not showing up

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am inserting google maps into my page. I used the code straight from this post: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)
With changes to the coordinates and zoom. But on my page the increase/decrease slider is not showing up like in the screenshot example given from the original posting.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['Lil Builders',  40.845816, -73.168143, 1],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.845816, -73.168143),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

screen shot from what I am seeing is here[image]

my page live is [HERE](http://lilbuilders.com/pages/contact3.htm)

Any ideas as to why? Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 : weird UI display glitches (with screenshot)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471830/google-maps-api-v3-weird-ui-display-glitches-with-screenshot)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map's Zoom look weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898973/google-maps-zoom-look-weird)

Comment: Adding #map img { max-width: none; } fixed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `#map img { max-width: none; }` fixed the issue.